# GWT Celltable IE9 issue

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

When I use KeyboardSelectionPolicy.DISABLED for TextInputCell in a celltable, the events are not fired correctly and hence FieldUpdater is not called at all the times.

My code snippet looks like this

```
 CellTable<String> cellTable = new CellTable<String>();
 cellTable.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.DISABLED);
 Column<String, String> column = new Column<String, String>(new TextInputCell()) {
@Override
public String getValue(String object) {
    //Do something
}
};
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<String, String>() {

@Override
public void update(int index, String object, String value) {
    //Do something
}
});
cellTable.addColumn(column);
```

Am I the only one facing this problem or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I remember seeing this in google issue tracker, I will post the link if I find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup I was right, This is reported in gwt issue tracker.

[Bug Id 7804](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?can=2&q=7804&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars&id=7804)

I found out this when I was tracking known IE issues for gwt.

I haven't tried out this yet, but it is reported. I will lookout for the issue tracker if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will keep track of it.